# Will a lemon tree grow back after being cut down low?

Tags: trees, citrus, lemons

My lemon tree was cut down very low by the person cutting my yard.  The tree was about two years old.  It was cut with a weed eater.

Comment: How big was the tree before this, and how low did they cut it? Please post a photo of the tree because that might give us more information.

Comment: You should post a picture...you might be able to get him to buy you another one.  Landscape maintenance people should have some kind of certification, licensed and bonded!  I hate it that just anyone and everyone thinks they are capable to maintain other people's yards with absolutely no training, no pesticide applicator license, just a pickup and a mower and blower and weed wacker.  By checking him out and making him get you another tree you are doing yourself and everyone a favor, not to mention raising the bar for this profession!   Grrrrr!

Comment: Check your homeowner's insurance as well.  You might have to ONLY hire someone licensed and bonded or your insurance is null and void.

Answer (score 7):

The smaller the tree was the more likely it is to grow back. Trees put on new growth by activating dormant buds along the length of the trunk. The smaller the branch or trunk the more dense those buds are. Be sure to keep grass and weeds growing around the stump/stub cut back and let light get to the bark.

Unfortunately no one can tell you for sure if your lemon will grow back until time has passed. Citrus trees are capable of growing back, but it's not guaranteed like it is with a willow or poplar tree for instance.

Comment: I'd add that if the severed end is stripped of bark, or badly twisted, cutting it back to healthy wood will help keep it from drying out

Answer (score 1):

If it grows back. Cut off above the graft. It will be more like a bush than a tree. Very small lemons if any. Be ahead removing it if for lemons. Some people do want lemon or fruit bush's. Ornamental